# how to access array in controller

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Hey there I need one help
I have "Products" table and "Services" table.There is an association between these two tables. 
'Products' belongs to 'Services' and 
'Services' has many 'Products'. 
I have to find for all 'Products' its corresponding all "Service_id's".

my code is:-

```
$products = $this->Product->query('select name from products');//retrives all products
for ($p=0; $p<count($products); $p++)
                {
                  $serviceid = $this->Product->query("select service_id from products where name = $products[$p][name]");//for each product finding its all corresponding service_id

                }
```

In above code  $product[$p][name] is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change the `$this->Product->query('select name from products');` for a cake method: `find('all');`

Since I'm not a fan of `$recursive != -1`, I'll put the code here if you want to avoid that recursion:

To find all products with it's correspondent services

```
$products = $this->Product->find('all', array('recursive'=>-1,
                                              'contain'=>array('Service')));
```

To find all services with its correspondent products it almost the same

```
$services = $this->Service->find('all', array('recursive'=>-1,
                                              'contain'=>array('Product')));
```

Do read [the methods of cake](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#retrieving-your-data) for this kind of thing, they save you a lot of time and sql-related-headaches when you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

First off please DO NOT DO this ever:

`for ($p=0; $p<count($products); $p++) {...`

Always assign the count to a variable:

`$productsCount = count($products);`

and then:

`for ($p=0; $p<$productsCount; $p++) {...`

When your count is in your loop it will get called every time. This has a tremendous effect on the time it takes for this statement to execute! This count is just a static integer value that you need and you surely do not need to calculate it every time.

**On your question:**

You can do this through the ORM since you already have the associations between the models in place, right?
This will give you all Product records with all associated Services:

```
$this->Product->recursive = 1;
$this->Product->find('all');
```

You can also go "the other way arround" but the `ServiceModel` must be available in the Controller (`Controller::$uses`).

```
$this->Service->recursive = 1;
$this->Service->find('all');
```

You can add contitions, fields to fetch, etc. in `Model::find()` - [look here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_find).

@Jueecy.new I already commented on this manner but the last bit in your example is absolutely prone to SQLInjection! Just try putting `DROP DATABASE someDB` through the HTML input field and watch the DB die... CakePHP does NOT cleanup mess like that. That's a specific feature of the `Model::query` method - it is used for hand-written queryes.

Answer (score 0):

Few Important Things..

**[IMP]  Do not fire any query in loop. Its very bad practice and will reduce your application performance up to lowest.**

1. In cake, you can find records for associate table as you mentioned products Belongs To Service. Hence your query should look like

   $this->Product->find('all');

As I can see u r looking for NAME and SERVICE_ID, Hence query will be

```
$this->Product->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Products.name','Service.id')));
```

This this case u no need to user recursive, as it takes

```
$this->Product->recursive = 2;
```

Hope this will be helpful to u..